How can I determine the duration of valid time remaining on a TOTP token countdown?
I'm studying concepts of OTP with a small application to generate and validate HOTP and TOTP tokens. I'm stuck on the formula used to determine the expiration in seconds of a TOTP token at any given time; the countdown value displayed in MFA mobile apps.
The formula described in Section 4 of RFC6238 suggests simply that TOTP = HOTP(K, T). I've not been able to observe this in practice.

Wiki's for TOTP Algorithm and HOTP Algorithm.

I started by testing the constituent components of the formula with static values in this Vanilla JavaScript example (42 lines, heavily commented). Each section describes the TOTP Algorithm accompanied by an associated variable or formula.
I'm expecting the final output to be a realistic integer representing the duration of time remaining before a token expires.
Provided static values T=now(), T0*=0 and X=30, the formula const Ct = Math.floor((T-T0) / X) produces 57075351, obviously not accurate.
I've also created this basic Angular implementation to incorporate scripted OTPAuth functionality.

OTPAuth GitHub, NPM Package, OTPAuth documentation.


What do you mean by “I've not been able to observe this in practice”?

I've not been able to produce the expected outcome in either of the examples I provided.

Get the number of seconds since the epoch:
const t = Date.now() / 1000;

The counter (what you’ve correctly calculated as Ct, which is not what you want) increments every 30 seconds starting at the epoch, so the time since the last one is
t % 30

making the time until the next one
30 - t % 30

